# NoMethodError: undefined method `quantity'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My pages are 
**line_items_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @cart = current_cart
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@line_item.cart,
                                  :notice => 'Line item was successfully created.') }
        format.json { render json: @line_item, status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**cart.rb**

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy

  def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
    else
      current_item = line_items.build(:product_id => product_id)
    end
    current_item
  end
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<ul>
  <% @cart.line_items.each do |item| %>
  <li> <%= item.quantity %> &times; <%= item.product.title %> </li>
      <% end %>
</ul>
```

**add_quantity_to_line_items.rb**

```
class AddQuantityToLineItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :line_items, :quantity, :integer, :default => 1
  end
end
```

When I click on add to cart button I get following error

```
 NoMethodError in LineItemsController#create
undefined method `quantity' for #<LineItem:0x007fad70aa26f0>

app/models/cart.rb:8:in `add_product'
app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:45:in `create'
```

Comment: Did you run the migration?

Comment: ... if you haven't already, run `rake db:migrate`

Comment: yes I run the migration and after that I get this error

Comment: if you run your migration on the right environment... you know? to make sure, use your favorite database viewer, look at the database table and see wether it has a `quantity` column.

Comment: restart the rails server

Answer (score 1):

To give you some context of the error, this basically means that it can't load a particular "column" value from your db:

```
undefined method `x'
```

The way around this is to ensure firstly that the column is in the database, and that your variable is going to load it (you're not using any select queries etc)

The comments you've received have questioned whether you've performed your migration correctly. The reason being that the migration has the `quantity` column ready to go -- so not having it available typically points to not having run the migration *or* not running in the correct environment